# Export a complex HTML made of <pattern> tags to SVG

Tags: python, html, svg

I created a data visualization with d3.js, then exported it as a static HTML file

[Here is a link to a repo with this file](https://github.com/rapminerz/stackoverflow_question)

Here is how it looks : [image]

Now I want to export this as a SVG file

I tried to do this with `wkhtmltopdf` in Python, but it is not saving it correctly (I think it is ignoring the `<pattern>` tags)

Here is the (bad) result I get : [image]

Do you know how I could export this as a proper SVG ?

Comment: Your file has typos: "preserveAspectRation" everywhere rather than the correct "preserveAspectRatio". Also, while href is supported in modern browsers, older tools might expect xlink:href="". It's also weird to have namespace declarations inside the image tag - usually that's done in the svg tag. If the conversion tool expects conventionally written SVG, it might to choke on those. Just some ideas.

Comment: Thanks ! I can see images now (with the preserveAspectRatio and xlink:href fixes). What do you mean by "It's also weird to have namespace declarations inside the image tag" ?

Comment: Well you've edited the file now (one reason why links to code are a bad idea - now the question doesn't make sense) - but in the original, it looked like there was an namespace declaration inside every image tag. It's no longer there, so maybe I imagined it.

Comment: Yep I moved it to the svg tag, you didnt imagine it :) I managed to display the texts aswell : I duplicated the text tags without filter="url(...)". The last issue is the colors changing when exporting to svg. Maybe a cmyk/rgb bad conversion ?

Comment: Your filter declarations also have typos. SVG is XML which is case sensitive so if you get your casing wrong, it's not supposed to render. (Chrome ignores casing - which it's not supposed to - but Firefox and Safari will do the right thing and not process it).  So that fecomponenttransfer should be feComponentTransfer. fegaussianblur should be feGaussianBlur ... etc.